# hiring postdoc : track-record versus acquaintance

Tags: postdocs

When you hire postdocs, if there is an applicant with strong publication track-record who used to be trained in institutions / groups that are completely unfamiliar to you, and there is other applicant with slightly less publication track-record in a research institution / group that you are familiar with, then do you prefer hire the latter?

Comment: I interview 3 or so people and make a decision based on many factors and considerations. It is never so black and white as you seem to imagine.

Comment: There is really no general answer. Look at the individuals.